# how to append payload of objects to a state, consisting of an array of objects, using spread operator..syntax issue in reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, spread

I'm trying to append a payload of data that is inputted in one screen and displayed on another screen. the data is held as an array of objects. How do you structure your reducer using the spread operator such that the previous states are persisted? I've tried two-three ways and given the error in a commented section of the reducer code. what is the right syntax?

reducer code:

```
const initial = {
    reports: []
    
};

export default function attendanceReducer(state = initial, action){
     switch(action.type) {
         case 'UPDATE_REPORTS':
            return {
                ...state,
                //reports: action.payload,  // no persistence
                reports: [...state.reports,...action.payload.reports] //TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable
                //reports: [state.reports, action.reports] //Returns nested arrays with nesting depth increasing for each action call of the form [[[]][]]
                
             };
        
         default:
             return state;    



     }
}
```

object:

```
    var reports = [];
            for(i=0;i<selectedItems.length;i++){
                var attendanceObj = {};
                attendanceObj["key"]=selectedItems[i];
                attendanceObj["name"]=selectedCatArray[i][0];
                attendanceObj["date"] = this.state.currDate;
                attendanceObj["qty1"]=1;
                attendanceObj["qty2"]=1;
                reports.push(attendanceObj);
            }
```

```
console.log('action.payload',action.payload):
```

> action.payload {"reports": [{"date": "2021-03-01", "key":
> "603a369d167abd00176bdd8f", "name":  "Plumbiggd", "qty1": 2, "qty2":
> 1}, {"date": "2021-03-01", "key": "603fd63bfe94590017b93921", "name":
> "Electricall", "qty1": 1, "qty2": 2}]}

```
console.log('this.state.report', this.state.report ):

 this.state.report [{"date": "2021-03-02", "key": "603a369d167abd00176bdd8f", 
 "name": "Plumbiggd", "qty1": 2, "qty2": 1}, {"date": "2021-03-02", "key": 
 "603c97c742b7b9001755d63b", "name": 
"Plumbing", "qty1": 1, "qty2": 3}]
```

Comment: Can you also give us the value of state.reports ? Probably that's the non-iterable instance javascript talking about. It's probably null or undefined

Comment: is your `state.reports` is an `Array`?

Comment: yes its an array of objects. I provided the console.log @Sayog

Comment: @UğurEren i added

Comment: @sayog I console.logged this.state.report only

Comment: What is your `initial state` of reducer ?? Show your full `reducer` code

Comment: @Sayog added intial state and whole reducer code.

Comment: You have to do `reports: [...state.reports,...action.payload.reports]` as `action.payload` is an object which is non iterable.